# Django - Ordering by a foreign key

Tags: python, django

I have a class that's called Movie:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=511)
    tmdb_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    release = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    poster = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True)
    backdrop = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    popularity = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and a class named Trailer:

```
class Trailer(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

How can I display all movies ordered by the date of the trailer?

I have tried: `Movie.objects.order_by('trailer__date')` but that causes multiple duplicates and doesn't show them on the right order either, how can I avoid the duplicates and have one entry per each movies ordered by the date of the Trailer object?

**Edit:** I just noticed that it doesn't display all entries but just some of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@2ps answer was close but didn't work as I would have liked, whether it was for ascending or descending order, but I finally figured out an answer based on his:

```
from django.db.models import Max

qs = Movie.objects.annotate(Max("trailer__date")).order_by('-trailer__date__max')
```

Answer (score 4):

Update:  the OP wanted this sorted by the latest trailer date, and not by the earliest trailer date.

You can use annotate here if you want:

```
from django.db.models import Max
qs = Movie.objects.values('title').annotate(latest_trailer=Max('trailer__date')).order_by('-latest_trailer')
# Add other columns you want into the `values` if you need them
```

Or you can use your original query and couple it with a dict.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
qs = Movie.objects.order_by('-trailer__date')
movies = OrderedDict()
for x in qs:
    if x.id not in movies:
        movies[x.id] = x
movies = movies.values()
```

It was unclear what order you wanted the movies in when they had multiple trailers, so I guessed it was based on the earliest trailer.

Comment: the first one raises an error of **NoReverseMatch at /movies/** and when I tried it with: `Movie.objects.annotate(earliest_trailer=Min('trailer__date')).order_by('earliest_trailer')` it showed the movies without duplicates, but not in the right order, and the order is based on the latest trailer. The second one raised an error: **'odict_values' object is not subscriptable** I'm not sure what that means

Comment: **Edit:** `Movie.objects.annotate(earliest_trailer=Min('trailer__date')‌​).order_by('earliest‌​_trailer')` does show all the objects however it's still in a random order

Comment: @mari:  uou don’t have enough code for us to help with the scriptable issue, and the above example has been updated to sort by latest trailer.  Please make sure to specify that in your original post next time.